# How can I have a field that is of type array in GraphQL?

Tags: php, api, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I need to enter multiple Ids to a field in my mutations. How can I achieve that seeing array is not included in the scalar type. I'm using Laravel `lighthouse` package.

I have tried to use `[]` to pass in the Ids but not working.

```
    mutation{
      syncPermissions(roleId: 1 permissions: [1, 2, 3]){
      name
   }
 }
```

I expect to access the permissions (in this case Ids) as an array in my resolve method.

Comment: Did the answer solve the problem for you? Then mark it as solved. 
Else we will gladly help you and see if we can find the your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You simply wrap the type in `[]`, in your schema.

Example:

```
extend type Mutation {
    syncPermissions(roleId: Int!, permissions: [Int!])
    @field(resolver: "MyResolver@update")
}
```